# Narrow `unknown` to an object with a string-field without using `any`

Tags: typescript

i'm trying to validate data that my application receives. a short example is the following:

```
function getField(data:unknown):string {
    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
        throw new Error('e1');
    }

    if (data == null) {
        throw new Error('e2');
    }

    const { field } = data;

    if (typeof field !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('e3');
    }

    return field;
}
```

i need to extract a string-field from the data. the code should throw if the shape of the data is invalid. the problem is, the above code does not typecheck. it fails with "Property 'field' does not exist on type '{}'.". i know i can add some `any` and it will work, but i'm trying to do this without `any`, in a type-safe way.

Answer (score 13):

There is a suggestion to allow the `in` type guard to asset the existence of properties but it is not implemented ([GH](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25720))

You can use a type assertion which should be safe enough (`const { field } = data as { field: unknown };`) or you can use a custom type guard to check for the existence of the property:

```
function hasProp<K extends PropertyKey>(data: object, prop: K): data is Record<K, unknown> {
    return prop in data;
}
function getField(data: unknown): string {
    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
        throw new Error('e1');
    }

    if (data == null) {
        throw new Error('e2');
    }
    if (!hasProp(data, 'field')) {
        throw new Error('field does not exist');
    }
    const { field } = data;

    if (typeof field !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('e3');
    }

    return field;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcAKAnOAHAHgGlEBTADylLABN1Ed9TsoBPI01gPgAobUoqAFyI4AIwBWpaABpEeXHhFEAlCP6DEMegCVpcbDWJzwAazBwA7mC6IA3gFgAUIleJspKCGxIF+LUgaqADczgC+zqCQsAiIAOaeAGIwpAA2NHwCwohmFtZqiOhQ2DBgcfbOblrAiDxseKRwNUGIAIQAvO2IAOTiUtDdKhUuVW5QyLiWiGCkUwCi2LjYPN2kAIyDoSOuEU6VbjA1mZqd0yCpqUOO26Pjk9OziAtLK6QATJv7O1-Vta1oWEUx1Qcm6wBS6UGVx+VTuVge80WBhW4LSNEQNDgpHoFigZHI2ignxuuyqEAQRXsiFR6UQYUQXSCWx+h1q9UaNRp6I6XW6RRKZUGw1GYwm8JmiJeqwAzMSqrsfh4vD5qRCaFswkA)

**Note** Since you are throwing exceptions, you might use the new assertion syntax: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=28&pln=3&pc=33#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcAKAnOAHAHgGlEBTADylLABN1Ed9TsoBPI01gPgAobUoqAFyI4AIwBWpaABpEeXHhFEAlCIzpmUev0GIY9AErS42GsTngA1mDgB3MF0QBvALAAoRF-3BEPAIQ8Cvj6SLqoKiouHt6xiFDIuHaIYKTJAKLYuNg8AAYAJM7BeAC+iDRwpPS2UGTkBlC5KgDcMd4lHh3uoJCwCIgA5qRQAGIwpAA2NHwCwojWtg5qiOhQ2DBgA9Ge3jC+PGx4pHC+4Yj+ALwXiADk4lLQN1FuO3HxifYpaYiZ2Tw3pAAjE9Wq9EF02l49n4zlcUiAJhNnpC4gkkl8MllTP9SAAmEEorqxNBYRQzQRyG7AcZTAlgiAIVYuRDUyY0cGIa7hUEo6EHVhHE4smnsy7XG6rdabJ7bN5eNGfVKYv4AgDMdNiELB2GGIGwSFZU1BJSAA)

Comment: thanks. unfortunately this still relies on the programmer not making mistakes (the `hasProp` function can have an empty body and it will still compile). i am trying to find a solution where that is not needed.

Comment: @gabor The hasProperty function can be defined once correctly and reused as many times as you need. Ts will not let you narrow the object using `in` and, at least for types there is no other option to go from `object` to something with other properties.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding Titian's example to tolerate a wider range of inputs (obj as just `unknown` and `key` as potentially null or undefined:

```
function hasProp<K extends PropertyKey>(obj: unknown, key: K | null | undefined): obj is Record<K, unknown> {
    return key != null && obj != null && typeof obj === 'object' && key in obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `in` as a type guard:

```
function getField(data: unknown): string {
  if (typeof data !== 'object') {
    throw new Error('e1');
  }

  if (data == null) {
    throw new Error('e2');
  }

  if (!('field' in data) || typeof data.field !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('e3');
  }

  return data.field;
}
```